# Join tables based on overlapping time intervals

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables with records that specify date intervals. The tables have two fields in common. The interval fields are expressed as two fields (from/to) that are used in both tables. I want to join them based on the common fields and overlapping intervals:

[image: Joining two tables with diff intervals]

How can I do this? I want all records from table 1, and when there is an overlap with the interval in table 2, I want that added in the result.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Your title states **overlapping time intervals**; your description states **overlapping date intervals** and your database structure implies **overlapping depth intervals**. Maybe this is something you need to sort out as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer join with a condition that expresses date overlaps:

```
select    t1.*, 
          t2.depth_from as from2, t2.depth_to as to2, t2.code as code2
from      table1 t1
left join table2 t2
       on t1.DataSet = t2.DataSet
      and t1.HoleID = t2.HoleID
      and t1.Depth_From < t2.Depth_To 
      and t1.Depth_To > t2.Depth_From
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables on the two common fields, and then limit the results to only those records where there is a complete or partial overlap of depth-ranges.  You did not specify which `RDBMS` you are using, so you may need to modify accordingly.

```
SELECT 
      t1.* 
    , t2.Depth_From AS DFrom
    , t2.Depth_To AS DTo
    , t2.Code AS Code
FROM
    table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
        ON t1.DataSet = t2.DataSet
            AND t1.HoleID = t2.HoleID
WHERE 
       (t1.Depth_From <= t2.Depth_From AND t1.Depth_To >= t2.Depth_To)
    OR (t1.Depth_From >= t2.Depth_From AND t1.Depth_To <= t2.Depth_To)
    OR (t1.Depth_From < t2.Depth_From AND t1.Depth_To > t2.Depth_From)
    OR (t1.Depth_From < t2.Depth_To AND t1.Depth_To > t2.Depth_To);
```